# if(value=="") why this block returning as false

Tags: java

Please, consider the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value="abc";
    value="";
    if(value==""){
        System.out.println("blank "+value);
    }
}
```

I do not understand why `if(value=="")` is returning as false.

Comment: Read up on the difference between the equality operator `==` and the `equals` method. Would have also taken roughly 2s of googling or using the search here.

Comment: Funnily on my jdk9.0.4 your snippet does print `blank `.

Answer (score 0):

`==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).

`.equals()` tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").

So make sure what you are testing and use the precise one

Comment: @kiranB: Did you tried with by changing `==` to `.equals()` ?

Comment: #kvmahesh Thnaks.  Its working fine with .equals()

Comment: That's sounds great. Thanks

Comment: Please confirm the answer which will help others to follow whenever they encounter that issue